# Multiply values from two dictionary but a pair of key and value not exist in one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries that need to multiply:

```
dict1 = {'fred': 2, 'andrew': 2, 'judy': 1, 'george': 1}
dict2 = {'andrew': 4, 'fred': 2, 'judy': 2, 'george': 1, 'john': 1}
```

I am using

```
count = {k: dict1[k]*dict2[k] for k in dict1}
```

It gives me the output:

```
{'fred': 4, 'andrew': 8, 'judy': 2, 'george': 1}
```

Because john is not included in dict1 but I need 'john' to have value of '0', is it possible?

How can I make it as:

```
count = {'fred': 4, 'andrew': 8, 'judy': 2, 'george': 1, 'john': 0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dict.get` and the union of your dictionary keys:

```
count = {k: dict1.get(k, 0) * dict2.get(k, 0) for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}
```

`dict.get` allows an optional default parameter, which is used if the key is not found in the dictionary.

Views of dictionary keys permit `set`-like operations, so we can use `|` to indicate the union between keys in two dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner code:

```
dict1 = {'fred': 2, 'andrew': 2, 'judy': 1, 'george': 1}
dict2 = {'andrew': 4, 'fred': 2, 'judy': 2, 'george': 1, 'john': 1}

# old code
print({k: dict1[k]*dict2[k] for k in dict1})
{'andrew': 8, 'george': 1, 'judy': 2, 'fred': 4}

# new code with if-else inside dictionary comprehension
print({k: dict1[k]*dict2[k] if k in dict1.keys() and dict2.keys() else 0 for k in dict2})
# output
{'john': 0, 'andrew': 8, 'george': 1, 'judy': 2, 'fred': 4}
```